# How does connecting the camera to a laptop help in photography?

Tags: tethering

From here: http://500px.com/photo/6330641

I asked him/her how did s/he photograph it? Holding the milk jug her/himself?
To which I got the reply:

> camera mounted on a tripod and **connected to a laptop**. pour the milk and shake the button :)

In what way does camera connected to a laptop help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By feeding the output of the camera to the laptop you can see what the camera is seeing *in real time* if you can't be behind the camera. You can position the laptop where you can see it's screen, then you can press the remote shutter release at exactly the right moment to capture the shot you are after.

Most useful, if, like the photographer in this case, you are working alone.

NOTE: You don't have to have software on the laptop to actually **control** the camera as you can use a remote for the camera.

How you view the image will depend on your camera. The term you need to search for is "tethering".

Comment: @AnishaKaul - I think it would depend on the camera as well.

Comment: @AnishaKaul - I'd Google/Bing for the make and model of your camera and the word "tethering" first. You might just find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[NKRemote](http://breezesys.com/NKRemote/index.htm) and other such software also allow you to precisely focus (by manually focusing) or control the focus directly on the laptop. This is done through the fact that the live view will show on the laptop screen which is way bigger and better than the camera's LCD.

You also will receive the NEF/JPG files directly on the laptop regardless of the card in the body.

You can also do [timelapses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timelapse) by using a laptop.

Comment: Is there a similar program to NKRemote for Canon?

Comment: I do not know but I'd be surprised if there isn't. The keywords which you could use to search would be Canon, tethering, timelapse, focus control, application.

Answer (score 0):

Taking images while camera is connected to a laptop/computer is very convenient, because it allows you to see the image the way it will look on your laptop (sometimes it looks not that good after downloading it from camera to computer) and in large size.  It helps to notice details and avoid mistakes.

I use this method often and it really makes a huge difference and saves me a lot of time.

I wrote an article about tethering as some people think that to shoot tethered an expensive piece of software is involved, which is not right. All you need is software and cable which come with your camera (for Canon) and off you go shooting.

Read full article here: 
http://dinablaszczak.hubpages.com/_stxprf1/hub/HowtoshoottetheredwithaCanoncameraStepbystepguide